# JPA join and join fetch one attribute at the same time

Tags: jpa, join

Is the following JPA query valid?  FETCH join and join one attribute at the same time:

```
SELECT mag FROM Magazine mag LEFT JOIN FETCH mag.articles
LEFT JOIN mag.articles a WHERE mag.id = 1 and a.name like "%FOO"
```

Join the Article table twice?

Comment: why not execute and see whether it works or not?

Comment: I am reading spec. A provider can implement it differently from spec.